# O controller pode enviar email?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, design-pattern, solid

Em um controller chamado atividades, tenho um metodo chamado lembrete.
Esse metodo, recebe um id, procura aquela atividade com base nesse id e envia um email pro moderador daquela atividade com dados da mesma.
Esse metodo esta com 'responsabilidades demais'?

Estou enviando dois metodos para já unir outra duvida. Por designer de código, qual deles está correto? O que envia separa a $client em uma variavel (reminder_a), ou o que sempre utiliza $activity para se referenciar aos clientes (reminder_b)?

Segue metodo:

```
/**
 * Send the remember email with a resource
 * @param  int $id
 */
public function reminder_a($id)
{

    $activity   = $this->activities->getById($id);
    $client     = $activity->client;

    $title = 'Reminder of activity ' . $activity->name;
    $view  = 'emails.activity.reminder';
    $data  = ['activity' => $activity, 'cliente' => $client];
    CustomMail::sendBasicMail($view, $title, $activity->client->email, $data);

}


/**
 * Send the remember email with a resource
 * @param  int $id
 */
public function reminder_b($id)
{

    $activity = $this->activities->getById($id);

    $title = 'Reminder of activity ' . $activity->name;
    $view  = 'emails.activity.reminder';
    CustomMail::sendBasicMail($view, $title, $activity->client->email, $activity);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poder, pode. Mas não é recomendado.

Comparando os dois métodos, me parece que a diferença é só passar o `client` separado da `activity`, o que pra mim não haveria necessidade já que um é atributo do outro. Sendo assim, me parece que o método `reminder_b` é mais correto.

Também não vejo nenhum erro na aplicação do princípio Single Responsibility Principle (o "S" de SOLID) pois cada método do controlador possui apenas uma responsabilidade, que é a de enviar o email.

A única coisa que eu mudaria (além de optar pelo método `reminder_b`) seria encapsular o envio de email, talvez colocá-lo dentro de um serviço. O controlador deve ser visto apenas como um ponto de entrada da sua aplicação (por exemplo, você poderia enviar o email também por meio da linha de comando), executar uma única tarefa e retornar uma resposta correspondente.

Espero ter sido claro. :)

Comment: Perfeito @Rodrigo. Sobre encapsular email, como eu iria passar informações como: a view a ser utilizada, titulo customizado e etc, se eu não chamar isso no metodo onde eu fiz a consulta de atividade?

Comment: Se você observar, posso utilizar o sendBasicMail pra qualquer tipo de email.

Comment: Se o `SendBasicMail` já encapsula bem a tarefa de enviar e-mails, talvez colocar mais uma camada de abstração (por exemplo, um serviço) não seja tão necessária. Mas o que eu faria, por exemplo, seria criar um método `sendActivityEmail`, para o qual você passaria a atividade ou, simplesmente, o `$id` dela. (nesse caso seria necessário injetar o repositório de atividades como uma dependência do serviço de envio de emails).

Comment: Humm.. Hoje meu sistema envia em media 24 tipos de emails diferentes. Teria um metodo pra cada um?  :/

Comment: Isso é bem questão de estilo. Como eu gosto de ter vários métodos nos quais cada um executa um determinado tipo de tarefa (e não uma única tarefa genérica), eu o faria. Aí vai muito da vontade do desenvolvedor. :)

Comment: Existe relatividade nisso né? Um repositorio por exemplo. Você não iria criar um metodo por cada consulta diferente.  :p

Comment: Claro que não, você agrupa de acordo com os parâmetros dos métodos até um estado aceitável :)

Comment: Obrigado @Rodrigo. A discussão foi bastante produtiva e sanou minha dúvida.